# Unable to find solution for $a^2+b^2-ab$, given $a^2+b^2-ab$ is a prime number of form $3x+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, prime-factorization

I have a list of prime numbers which can be expressed in the form of $3x+1$. One such prime of form $3x+1$ satisfies the expression: $a^2+b^2-ab$.

Now I am having list of prime numbers of form $3x+1$ (i.e., $7,19 \ldots$). But I am unable to find the $a$ and $b$ which satisfy the above expression.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just to know what you want exactly: You are looking for a prime, say $p$, which is congruent $1$ mod $3$ such that there are integers/primes (??) $a,b$ such that $p = a^2 + b^2 - ab$?

Comment: Yes exactly a & b should be integers and a < b , and p is the prime of form 3x+1 ( 1 mod 3).

Comment: Are you trying to show that *every* prime of the form $3x+1$ can be written in the form $a^2+b^2-ab$?  Note that $7=3^2+1^2-3\cdot1$, $13=4^2+1^2-4\cdot1$, and $19=5^2+2^2-5\cdot2$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the identity $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$, and note that, by *Little Fermat*, $x^3\equiv x\mod 3$, so $a^3+b^3\equiv a+b  \mod3$. Hence, if $a+b\not\equiv 0\mod 3$, necessarily $a^2-ab+b^2\equiv 1\mod3$.

Now suppose you've found $a$ and $b$ such that $a^3+b^3$ is the product of two primes. Then one of them will be congruent to $1\bmod 3$, and have the required form.

Computing some values yields $1^3+4^3=(1+4)(1^2-1\cdot 4+4^2)=5\cdot 13$. Thus $13$ is a solution.

Comment: you had 2 minor typos.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find them. Where?

Comment: $1^3+6^3=217=7\cdot 31$,...$1^3+16^3=4097=17 \cdot 241,$ ...I wonder if $a^2-a b+b^2$ can be a prime congruent to $1$ mod $3$ when $ a+b$ is composite.

Comment: I already edited the typos out. I feel that when I edit someone else that I should tell them what I did.

Comment: I already have the solution for  a^2-ab+b^2 (i.e : 13) .                                  I need help in computing  values of a & b ?

Comment: @user254665: $1^3+5^3$ is a counterexample: it's neither prime, nor congruent to $1$. In my argumentation, the fact that $a^3+b^3$  is the product of *two* primes is essential.

Comment: What I said was :" if it can be prime", not whether it must be. I found an example: $5^2-5\cdot 3+3^2=25-15+9=19$ while $5+3=8$ is composite. I gave you a  +1 for your A.

Comment: @balaji. I suspect that finding all values a,b, or even finding out whether there is a finite or infinite set of them may very deep and maybe unsolvable at the present state of the art.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?
$$(-2)^2+1^2-(-2)\cdot 1=7=3\cdot 2+1$$